# How to use the field calculator in QGIS to determine the total of differents fields

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, calculate-values

I have an attribute table with 7 fields.[image: Attribute table test]

I want my attribute " A1 " to be the total of " IP1 to IP5 ". I am not familiar with the request in the field calculator.

How can I calculate the value of one field so it represents the total of other fields ?

Comment: "IP1" + "IP2" + "IP3" + "IP4" + "IP5"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read more about the documentation [here](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html). You'll find the different operators available as well as an overview of the tool and sound methods.

Essentially, you want to "add" all values in each of those individual fields and create a "total" field represented by field "A1". You can use the field calculator tool within the options of field "A1".

[image]